# WPF Image Control binding in trigger not working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, wpf-controls

I have an `Image` control bound to two `Bitmap` Property (these are not dependency properties) in the viewmodel. The source is switched based on a toggle button. The trigger bound to toggle button works and switches the image source but The image is not updated when either of the `Bitmap` property is changed. The default image (which was initially set) is shown but not updated when the properties are changed. The viewmodel has INotifyPropertyChanged implemented and other parts of the code is notified when bitmap changes but the `Image` control is not updated.

The converter is only called at the beginning when initial images are set but not in subsequent updates.

```
<Image Grid.Row="1" 
                Stretch="Uniform" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                Width="Auto"
                Height="Auto">
                <Image.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ToggleImage}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Source" Value="{Binding ProcessedImage, Converter={StaticResource ImageToSourceConverter},
                                     UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWay}" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ToggleImage}" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="Source" Value="{Binding OriginalImage, Converter={StaticResource ImageToSourceConverter},
                                     UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWay}" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </Image.Style>
            </Image>
```

Here's The Converter Code

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Interop;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

namespace OMR_Scanner_Application.Converters
{
    class ImageToSourceConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
                System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            Bitmap image = value as Bitmap;
            if (image != null)
            {
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Bmp);
                ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
                bi.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.None;
                bi.BeginInit();
                bi.StreamSource = ms;
                bi.EndInit();
                return bi;
            }
            return null;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
            object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you tried to set *Twoway* instead of 'UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWay' ?

Comment: Nope. Doesn't work with `Mode=Twoway` either

Comment: Can you please post the Converter's code?

Comment: did you try to trigger PropertyChanged event of ProcessedImage and OriginalImage after ToggleImage is changed?

Comment: No. But i tried it just now. doesn't make any difference. The `Bitmap` Properties were already being updated in the code and `PropertyChanged` was being triggered but the `Image` Control is not updating

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code. It works fine for me, assumed that the `ToggleImage` property fires a PropertyChanged event. The error may be somewhere in your view model. As a note, I would however suggest to modify the converter code so that it disposes of the MemoryStream (although not strictly necessary) by means of a using block. You would then also have to set `BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad`.

Comment: I used about the same code for a previous version of this project. But now needing to redo the project again using parts of the old code.
It worked in the previous project. but in the new one it doesn't work.
The properties update just fine and other code is notified (as an example a listener writes the updated image to a file) but the image control is not updated.